# Live or living which is common error?

Tags: neologisms

1. I am living in London for a few months.
2. I have been living in London for a few months.

What is the difference?

Is number one a common error?

Answer (score 0):

(a) Means 'London, and not some other place.'  If you have two houses, if you know that you won't be staying in London for more than a few months, or if the person you are talking to expects you to be somewhere else, you would say:

> (a) I am living in London for a few months

If you just want to say where you are living, say:

> (b) I have been living in London for a few months.
>   or (c) I shall be living in London for a few moths.